# How to display modal on the basis of Access token

Tags: android, react-native

I am not able to display a Modal on Post a review button if user is logged in successfully. I am receiving access token in API but my modal is not opening.

**Review Screen**

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Modal,
} from 'react-native';
import { Button, Paragraph, Wrapper } from '../components';
import { baseStyle, images, theme, routes } from '../config';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext';


export const Reviews = ({ route }) => {
    const {userInfo} = useContext(AuthContext);
    const navigation = useNavigation();


    const [isModalVisible, setisModalVisible] = useState(false);
    const { item } = route.params;
    const [responseData, setResponseData] = React.useState();



    React.useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://6895-202-47-60-211.ngrok-free.app/listing/${item.id}/feedback`)
            .then(response => {
                setResponseData(response.data.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, [item]);


    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <View style={styles.header} >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                    <Image source={images.back} style={styles.backIcon} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                < Text style={styles.headerText} > Reviews </Text>
            </View>
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.review} >
                {responseData &&
                    responseData.length > 0 &&
                    responseData.map((item) => (
                        <View style={styles.reviewContainer}>
                            <View style={styles.flex} >
                                <Paragraph style={styles.reviewer} > {item.name} </Paragraph>
                            </View>
                            <Paragraph>
                                {item.feedback_desc}
                            </Paragraph>
                        </View>
                    ))
                }
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.footer} >
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Button onPress={userInfo.data ?  (
                    <Modal
                      transparent={true}
                      animationType='fade'
                      visible={isModalVisible}
                    > Text </Modal>) :
                    navigation.navigate(routes.LOGIN, {item:item})}> Post a review </Button>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </Wrapper>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginBottom: baseStyle.marginBottom(32),
        paddingHorizontal: baseStyle.paddingHorizontal(15),
    },
    backIcon: {
        width: baseStyle.width(36),
        height: baseStyle.height(36),
    },
    headerText: {
        fontFamily: theme.font.bold,
        fontSize: baseStyle.fontSize(16),
        lineHeight: baseStyle.lineHeight(19),
        color: theme.colors.black,
        marginLeft: baseStyle.marginLeft(75),
    },
    review: {
        paddingHorizontal: baseStyle.paddingHorizontal(15),
    },
    reviewContainer: {
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.lightGrey,
        paddingVertical: baseStyle.paddingVertical(15),
        paddingHorizontal: baseStyle.paddingHorizontal(15),
        borderRadius: baseStyle.borderRadius(16),
        marginBottom: baseStyle.marginBottom(15),
    },
    flex: { flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' },
    reviewer: {
        opacity: 1,
        fontFamily: theme.font.bold,
        marginBottom: baseStyle.marginBottom(10),
    },
    starIcon: {
        width: baseStyle.width(15),
        height: baseStyle.height(15),
        resizeMode: 'contain',
    },
    date: { marginTop: baseStyle.marginTop(10) },
    footer: {
        borderTopLeftRadius: baseStyle.borderTopLeftRadius(32),
        borderTopRightRadius: baseStyle.borderTopRightRadius(32),
        paddingVertical: baseStyle.paddingVertical(18),
        paddingHorizontal: baseStyle.paddingHorizontal(18),
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.white,
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: -5,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 1,
        elevation: 5,
        shadowColor: theme.colors.silver,
        shadowRadius: 6,
    },
});
```

API Logs

LOG  {"success": true, "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2ODY1NjIwODQsImV4cCI6MTY4NjY0ODQ4NH0.7uiji6h1ziMlYHcXUXJJ3TiQFXf8NB65sfRIXCT9sxI"}
LOG  {"data": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3RAY28uY28iLCJpYXQiOjE2ODY1NjIxMDgsImV4cCI6MTY4NjY0ODUwOH0._gX321NMJq1c4HctL8fkESrV8qvOQfVYzaftz9Sxbys", "message": "Account logged in", "success": true}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the error is because you're trying to render the `<Modal/>`component in the wrong place. Try to render the modal like this:

```
//...rest of your code
    <View style={styles.footer} >
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Button onPress={userInfo.data ? setisModalVisible(true) :
                    navigation.navigate(routes.LOGIN, {item:item})}> Post a review </Button>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
                <Modal
                      transparent={true}
                      animationType='fade'
                      visible={isModalVisible}
                    > Text </Modal>
     </Wrapper>
```

You have to set the state `isModalVisible` to true, you can't render an JSX element inside an `onPress` function.

Test and see if it's correct, if it isn't please report an we can try to find another answer.

Comment: I am getting the following error,
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: I resolved the issue by adding () => setisModalVisible(true)